# With in the toolbar tasks option will be missing in my xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am install the sdk every thing wil be k. But i am open the project the task option (with in the tool bar near to build and run) will be missing please help me.

Thanks,
subbu.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe the toolbar is set to hidden?

[image]

Comment: Please accept the answer when it solved you'r problem. Here's why and how to do it: [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)